# UISwitch not working properly in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction, uiswitch

I have taken a UISwitch control in my new swift project. And the default state of this is set as `Off` from storyboard. I have bounded it as IBOutlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var SwitchRemFacility: UISwitch!
```

I have also bounded it to a method by Value change event from storyboard.

```
@IBAction func rememberFacilityClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        print(SwitchRemFacility.on)
        if SwitchRemFacility.on {
            SwitchRemFacility.setOn(false, animated: true)
        } else {
            SwitchRemFacility.setOn(true, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

The Problem is that `SwitchRemFacility.on` returns always true here. I have checked by breakpoint and also I have printed it to console. Any hep will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing it when value is already changed. Switch will do it's on and off work by it self.

If you want to do it manually you can do like :

```
@IBAction func switchChangeVal(sender: AnyObject) {
    let swh : UISwitch = sender as! UISwitch
    if(swh.on){
        swh.setOn(true, animated: true)//But it will already do it. 
    }
    else{
        swh.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Actually no need of code. But if you want to condition on the on or off state then you have to do code.

### For Example

```
@IBAction func switchChangeVal(sender: AnyObject) {
    let swh : UISwitch = sender as! UISwitch
    if(swh.on){
        //Do the code for when switch is on
    }
    else{
        //Do the code for when switch is off
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean no need of value change event if I want to just on and off condition ?

Comment: @Max Yes. you no need to change the value manually. Switch will do it self

Comment: You can print the value of true or false and work on the true or false condition. no need to change state of switch.

Comment: @Max Updated the answer. hope it help you.

Comment: yes. Thank you. I forgot that Value changed event was fired after value changed.

Comment: @Max Yes. You got it. Welcome Anytime :)